# Checking multip hash keys if present

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Any tips to refactor this condition?

```
 params = {:p1=>"foo", :p2=>true, :p3=>nil, :pN=>""}

 if params[:p1].present? && params[:p2].present? && params[:pN].present?
  # do something...
```

Comment: Refactoring requests are kinda offtopic here. There's a site for that: http://codereview.stackexchange.com

Comment: Just a point, Code Review only takes **real** code. "Foo", "Bar" etc. will get closed in seconds. If you have that condition in an actual project somewhere, post the actual code.

Comment: Why is `p3` not being checked in `if` condition?  Are you not interested in values of all keys but only select few?.  Also, why you are using string `"p1"` in `params["p1"]`, when the key is actually a symbol `:p1` - both are not same.

Comment: @Wand, suppose you were looking for candidates for a rugby team and  `params = { :strong->true, :fast=>true, :downton_abbey_fan=>true,  :rugby_experience=>false  }`.

Comment: @CarySwoveland Point taken, I was just thinking if OP used key `:pN` instead of `:p4`, may be (s)he missed to use `:p3` in `if` even though (s)he meant to check keys `p1` through `pN`.  So, thought of clarifying.

Comment: @WandMaker There are many keys in the hash and I am only interested in some.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Something like this:

```
params.values_at(:p1, :p2, :pN).all?(&:present?)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
if params.values_at(*%i[p1 p2 p3]).all?(&:present?)
```

`values_at` returns an `Array` of the values for each key you provide.
`all?` is `true` iff the predicate (`present?`) is `true` for every member of the enumerable. `values_at` will include `nil` for a missing key (rather than omit it), so you don't need to worry about the array collapsing down to only present values.

Answer (score 1):

```
keys = [:p1, :p2, :pN]

puts "hi" if keys.all? { |k| params[k].present? }
```

This has the advantage of terminating the hash lookup as soon as `params[k].present?` is `false`.

Comment: Instead of `keys`, one can use `params.keys` given that `params` is a hash.  If I am not mistaken, OP seems to be checking whether all keys have value `present?`.

Comment: @Wand, the OP doesn't seem to care about `:p3`.

Comment: I see.  Strange though!